# React-native Google Drive how to get list of files and folders

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api

I have used react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper in my project, I can log in successfully and create files and folders, but I am not able to list the files stored in my drive. 
I am using react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper given in this link-- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper , 
To get the list of files and folders, mentioned code in above link is:

```
     GDrive.files.list({q: "'root' in parents"});
```

My code is :

```
     GDrive.files.list({q: "'root' in parents"})
             .then(response =>{ alert("response is "+JSON.stringify(response))
                  console.log(response.url)                      
            })
             .catch(er=> alert("error is" +er));
```

The response I get is,

```
     {"type":"default","status":200,"ok":true,"headers":{"map":{"content-securi
     ty-policy":"frame-ancestors 'self'","content-type":"application/json; charset=UT
     F-8","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","vary":"O
     rigin, X-Origin","date":"Wed, 22 Apr 2020 17:31:18 GMT","cache-control":"private
     , max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform","server":"GSE","alt-svc":"quic=\":44
     3\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2
     592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\
     "; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","
     expires":"Wed, 22 Apr 2020 17:31:18 GMT"}},"url":"https://www.googleapis.com/dri
     ve/v3/files?q=%27root%27%20in%20parents","_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":654,"offse
     t":0,"blobId":"7dbd3276-ae80-4e6e-85bd-04e2766787b7","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBl
     ob":{"_data":{"size":654,"offset":0,"blobId":"7dbd3276-ae80-4e6e-85bd-04e2766787
     b7","__collector":{}}}}
```

How am I suppose to get List of all the files stored in Google Drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I think it was just the difference of JSON.stringify(response) and res.json().
Anyways you can use this code

```
    GDrive.files.list({
              q: "'root' in parents",
             })
              .then(res=>res.json())
              .then(data=>alert(data.files[1].name)) //data.files is the array containing list of files 
              .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Thanks to https://github.com/RobinBobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper/issues/19#issue-571412310 , I copied his way of getting the data.